# Populate Checkedlistbox with Servers

Tags: powershell, powershell-studio

I am trying to populate a list with the servers in my domain, and i have partial success. There are 5 items in my list, which is as many servers as i have.

Unfortunately they are all just called [Collection]

Form is generated with Sapien Powershell Studio

```
$strCategory = "computer"
$strOperatingSystem = "Windows*Server*"

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain

$objSearcher.Filter = ("OperatingSystem=$strOperatingSystem")

$colProplist = "name"
foreach ($i in $colPropList) { $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i) }

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
{

    $objComputer = $objResult.Properties;
    $objComputer.name
    $checkedlistbox1.Items.add($objComputer.name)
}
```

What can I do to have the proper name show up in the checkedlist.

Thanks for any assistance :)

Comment: You just want to change column name in datagridview control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result object from `DirectorySearcher.FindAll()` method contains a special property named `Properties` that returns a typed **collection** containing the values of properties of the object found in the AD.

This means that you can simply do

```
. . . 

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach ($objResult in $colResults) {
    $checkedlistbox1.Items.add($objResult.Properties['name'][0])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Get-ADComputer instead to get the list of your servers.

The you just loop thrue the list and add the servername to your checkedlist

```
$Servers= Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like 'Windows *Server*'} #-Property * #the property flag is not needed if you just want the Name (see comment from Theo)
foreach ($srv in $Servers) {
    #Unmark to debug
    #$srv.Name
    #$srv.OperatingSystem   

    $checkedlistbox1.Items.add($srv.Name)
}
```

Comment: `-Property *` is a bad idea performance wise. The property `Name` is always returned. If you want the extended property `OperatingSystem` too, then you ask for it like `-Property OperatingSystem`. You can read about default and extended properties [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12056.active-directory-get-adcomputer-default-and-extended-properties.aspx)

Comment: @Theo PS-Newbei myself, so thank you, you taught me something new :)